# How to reduce ldf file size if we have applied replication on database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a Database that is using replication. Now I want to reduce the LDF file size (currently the size of the LDF is 6 GB).

I did "shrink" the LDF files, but it shrank only a few MBs. We need to look for other options for it because these database are using replication. Is any solution available for it?

Answer (score 11):

You should change database recovery model to "**simple**" and then use

`dbcc shrinkdatabase('database_name')`.

After this you will have an empty log.

Then do not forget to change recovery model back to "**Full**"

Comment: "Recover model" not "recovery mode" (according to the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx)